# node.js https server.listen throws getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND example.com

Tags: node.js, express, https

I got an express javascript server running on a Debian 7 server. I set it up about 8-10 days ago and it was working fine. I could request all the available paths and got the correct responses.

Today I realized that for some reason, requesting https://example.com:1234/examplepath didn't work anymore. I logged on to my server and saw the express server was still running, but no requests made it through. So I stopped the server and tried to start it again. But what worked 8-10 days ago now suddenly throws the error

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^

Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND example.com
    at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

**Here is the relevant code of my server.js.**

```
const app = express();
const helmet = require('helmet');
app.use(helmet());
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
    directives: {
        defaultSrc:["'self'"]
    }
}));
app.use(helmet.expectCt());
app.use(helmet.noCache());
app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy());

const port = 1234;
const hostname = 'example.com';

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem')
};

...

MongoClient.connect(db.url, (error, database) => {
    if (error) return console.log(error);

    require('./app/routes')(app, database.db("placeholder"), config);

    https.createServer(options, app).listen(port, hostname, () => {
        console.log('We are live on ' + hostname + ':' + port);
    });
});
```

Creating the server with **https.createServer** works, but calling **listen()** throws the error mentioned at the top. The certificates are up to date and doing **.listen(port, 'localhost', ()** works fine.

I didn't change anything in the code or on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out my domain provider messed up. Everything works again.